# example source code for an iPhone application that shows Edit/Delete/Add rows for a UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

Any suggestions for some sample source code for an iPhone application that shows Edit/Delete/Add rows for a UITableView?

The code would highlight the typical way to have a UITableView and then use editing mode and various methods (callbacks) to implement Edit/Delete/Add.

(have looked at the Apple examples and see things like Table View Suite, however it doesn't show what I'm after here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The apple sample code has good examples for these, but here is a pretty detailed tutorial I found a while back that should get you headed in the right direction.

[iPhone SDK Tutorial – {Part 5}: Add, Delete & Reorder UITableView Rows](http://adeem.me/blog/2009/05/29/iphone-sdk-tutorial-add-delete-reorder-uitableview-row/)

Comment: thanks zzzzz - it looks good - but it doesn't seem to give the example for EDIT?  seems to have only add & delete use cases covered?

Comment: You would have to implement the 'edit button' yourself and it wouldn't be as easy as the others. You would have to add a button to the rows when in editing mode. For example have a test in your cellForRowAtIndexPath for tableView.editing and when in editing mode add a button to the rows which calls your desired editing function you will write.